# Logic Apps parse large json files (up to 300MB)

Tags: parsing, azure-logic-apps, large-files

I have an Azure Logic app which runs daily and downloads up to 300MB of json data (approximately 300k objects).
I then need to iterate over the items and transform before I push to an Azure Service Bus.
Are there any best practices for doing this? I have a stateful workflow on WS1 scaling, and after 3 hours it still haven't managed to parse it.
The service I'm getting data from cannot split it into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any best practices for doing this?

You are doing the correct only, but you need to on the **`Concurrency Control`** like below:

[image]

Concurrency Control is used to run all items parallelly in For_Each loop to make execution fast.

If you want to divide the data or file into chunks, you can use Azure Functions connector( In functions , you can divide data into chunks and send back the response to logic apps).

[image]